Can different random variables have different samples and sample spaces for the same experiment?
Suppose we have an experiment consisting in throwing a six-sided die. Let X be a random variable representing the number at the top of the die after throwing it. Let Y be a random variable representing if the result is even.
I first thought that both random variables had sample space $\Omega=\{1,2,3,4,5,6\}$. This way, I can define
$$X(\omega)=\omega\ \ \forall\omega\\
Y(\omega)=
\begin{cases}
1 \quad \text{if} \ \omega\ \text{is even} \\
0 \quad \text{otherwise}
\end{cases}
$$
but know I'm doubting that it perhaps is more like
$$\Omega_X=\{1,2,3,4,5,6\}\\
\Omega_Y=\{even, odd\}$$
In the case of this latter definition, I'm guessing that we would need different samples, even if they are the same in the underlying experiment? Something like
$$
\{4,3,6,1,2,5,6,2,...\}\\
\{even, odd, even, odd, even, odd, even, even,...\}
$$

Not sure what you are asking.  "sample spaces" are models based on the situation and what it is you plan to ask about it.  Here, it seems perfectly reasonable to just consider the $6$ possible tosses (or a sequence of these) as your sample space.  Of course, in practice, if you care about some aspects but not others you can throw out the irrelevant parts.  When teachers give exams, they typically aren't interested in the color of the students' shoes so they'd leave that data out of the sample space.  Is that what you are asking?

To stress;  there is no harm in retaining irrelevant data, other than possibly slowing computation time and wasting storage space.  And, of course, later on you might find out that shoe color really is a key predictive variable for test scores.  There are choices and trade offs at various points.

It is your first one with $X(\omega)=\omega$ and $Y(\omega) = 1{\omega : even}$. A probability experiment has one sample space. All random variables for that experiment are functions from the same space to the real numbers.

In your $(\Omega, \mathcal F, \mathbb P)$ probability space with random variables $X:\Omega \to E_X^{,}$, $Y:\Omega \to E_Y^{,}$, you do not need $(\Omega, \mathcal F, \mathbb P)$ to change in order to have $X$ and $Y$ different or indeed $E_X^{,}$ and $E_Y^{,}$ different.  If you want a sequence of samples here, you might have $\Omega = {1,2,3,4,5,6}^{\mathbb N }$ or even something more complicated.
